# Bootstrap 3.0 Not Scrollable

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap 3.0 website does not seem to be able to scroll...

I removed all custom CSS and tried as indicated in the below link to no avail. Here is a snipit of the HTML

[Bootstrap 3.0 app not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409510/bootstrap-3-0-app-not-scrolling)

```
<body>
    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container" ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
            <h3><b><i>{{title}}</i></b></h3>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... (many lines)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure this is related but you have an unclosed div 3rd line from bottom.

Comment: Just a typo but thanks all the same.

Comment: When I pop your code into Bootply and add 10 paragraphs of lorem ipsum text, it scrolls just fine. http://www.bootply.com/0jA84IQKwT

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was hoping I was just doing something ignorant. I am using the angular-fullstack yeoman generator and it must be something to do with that. There are so many minor tweaks I have made it almost seems an insurmountable task to find it...